# Styling colors of select box (with custom wrapper) dropdown text with css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have select dropdown box with some custom css styling made possible with `styled-select` wrapper:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="styled-select">
<select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class="">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.styled-select {
      background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 84% 0;
      height: 29px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 70px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #1abc9c;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

 .styled-select select {
       background: transparent;
       border: none;
       font-size: 14px;
       color: #000;
       height: 29px;
       padding: 5px; 
       width: 90px;
    }
```

[Link to JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7Lc5vwr/1/)

I am trying to change the color of selected value in a select box (10 is showing by default) to white, while keeping other items in dropdown dark.

I get the desired effect by changing color to white in `select` css, but it also make other items in dropdown white, which makes them invisible if select box placed on white background. If I change background of dropdown to some dark color, it overwrites the color of styled select box.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the following to your CSS:

```
option:not(:checked) {
  color: #000;
}
```

And changing the default color on the `.styled-select select` to `color:#fff`, this way the options that weren't selected will have a black text color, while the selected one has a white text color

For more on the `:not()` selector go [here (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

For more on the `:checked` selector go [here (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried it and it works but there is one issue: when I click on select box, dropdown opens and the current option (10) is selected by default and its visible, when i move mouse down the list, current item is not visible anymore unless moused over again. Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7Lc5vwr/2/) with your code

Comment: @Acidon This is because you've explicitly told CSS to set the selected item's color to White, since the selected item's background in the dropdown is blue, you see the white text, if you want to avoid this, I think you'll have to use jQuery

Comment: the interesting part it works fine on mobile devices, and anyway its not such a big issue afterall, accepting now

Answer (score 1):

did you meant something like that? I think, that you need to use as well some jquery or something like that:

```
<div class="styled-select">
  <select id="source" name="example_length" aria-controls="example">
    <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
  </select>
```

jquery for making it stylable and as well dropdown:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   createDropDown();

   $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
     $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
   });

   $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
     var $clicked = $(e.target);
     if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
       $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
   });

   $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
     var text = $(this).html();
     $(".dropdown dt a").html(text);
     $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();

     var source = $("#source");
     source.val($(this).find("span.value").html())
   });
 });

 function createDropDown() {
   var source = $("#source");
   var selected = source.find("option[selected]");
   var options = $("option", source);

   $("body").append('<dl id="target" class="dropdown"></dl>')
   $("#target").append('<dt><a href="#">' + selected.text() +
     '<span class="value">' + selected.val() +
     '</span></a></dt>')
   $("#target").append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>')

   options.each(function() {
     $("#target dd ul").append('<li><a href="#">' +
       $(this).text() + '<span class="value">' +
       $(this).val() + '</span></a></li>');
   });
 }
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/bbnso2og/4/

Here you can find long explanation and how to, I've got inspirated there as well: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The color of current select option has to be white all the time, not only on mouseover. Also, I would prefer to solve the problem with css only, and will go for js solution only as the last resort

Comment: Here you go with white: http://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/bbnso2og/5/ I dont think so that you can manipulate with select options. if yes, I would love to see it.